# How to put C# Loop Statements in console applications : Shapes rectangle, circle and square

Tags: c#, algorithm, console, console-application, shapes

I want to put a loop statement around the code below. Currently it calculates the area of circle, square and  rectangles. I want to put a do while statement that allows to check from a selection. When the person selects the shapes, inputs the sides of the shapes (radius if circle) then calculate the area, perimeter and dimensions. Please Help.

```
namespace ShapeCalc
{
    class CalcAvgPerc
    {             
        public float length, breadth, radius, side, hieght, breadthfortriangle;  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            CalcAvgPerc a = new CalcAvgPerc## Heading ##();  
            a.Rectangle();  
            a.Circle();  
            a.Square();  
            a.Triangle();  
            Console.ReadKey();
        }  
        public void Rectangle()  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Length for Rectangle");  
            length = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the breadth for Rectangle");  
            breadth = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);  
            Console.WriteLine("Area of rectangle is :{0}", length * breadth);  
        }  
        public void Circle()  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Radius of the Circle");  
            radius = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);  
            Console.WriteLine("Area of Circle is:{0}", 3.14 * radius * radius);  
        }  
        public void Square()  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the side of a square");  
            side = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);  
            Console.WriteLine("Area of Square is:{0}", side * side);  
        }  
        public void Triangle()  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Breadth for Triangle ");  
            breadthfortriangle = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Hieght for Triangle ");  
            hieght = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);  
            Console.WriteLine("Area of Triangle is:{0}", (breadthfortriangle * hieght) / 2);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Next time please specify what you have tried and what is not working rather than just asking us to write the code. Basically what you want to do here is add a do while loop in main function that checks the readkey at the end of your functions. If the next key is not 'Q' for quit for example, then you want to continue and repeat the whole thing. Also FYI, your shapes are not "shape" objects, they are just methods that ask questions related to the shape.

Comment: You should be more clear about the end result you are envisioning and what you have tried. If this is homework (it seems like it might be) That's OK but you should explicitly mention that as different community standards apply (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Being clear about what actions the user will take, and what the code will do will help everyone involved.

Comment: If i can clarify the question is part of a homework that was given to me: "Write a class-based program which allows the user to select and create several types of shapes: circles, triangles, squares and rectangles. Include methods to set and report on their position, dimensions, area, perimeter and so on, and overloaded Overlaps methods to check whether any shape overlaps another." The aim to write it in a loop statement.

Comment: That is what I was saying on my last point, you are not doing this from a "class-based" approach at all. You need to create classes with getters and setters, methods to calculate area, perimeter, etc... Your console program is just taking input and then outputting text after some calculations, which is not what your assignment is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to do... something like this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{
    alcAvgPerc a = new CalcAvgPerc();
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Select Shape: (R)ectangle, (C)ircle, (S)quare, (T)riangle:");
        var key = Console.ReadKey();
        switch (key.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.R:
                a.Rectangle();
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.C:
                a.Circle();
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.S:
                a.Square();
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.T:
                a.Triangle();
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting...")
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i can clarify the question is part of a homework that was given to me: "Write a class-based program which allows the user to select       
     and create several types of shapes: circles, triangles,           
     squares and rectangles. Include methods to set and report         
     on their position, dimensions, area, perimeter and so on,         
     and overloaded Overlaps methods to check whether any shape        
     overlaps another." The aim to write it in a loop statement.

Comment: That is not a question, it is a small project and there are several points you have to address.

Comment: essentially i want to write a loop statement for console application. The case statement should allow for the person to select either circle, square or rectangle. Once that happens allow the user to write the dimensions. Thirdly it should calculate the perimeter, area and display that accordingly.

Comment: nuno's answer gives you an idea of how to wrap the whole program in a loop, which answers your question as far as I can tell. You should accept it if you agree that it fixed your problem